# not able to see BLE device in android

Tags: android, android-bluetooth

I tried running Bluetooth low energy sample code from android on two different android phone that has `Android Lollipop` installed and it supports `BLE 4.0` too. but when i run the app and try to scan it , i am not able to get the name of other device in a list.

i am running this sample on Micromax android one.i am pretty new to BLE , so i am not sure i can see other `BLE` supported mobile phones in a list not just the peripherals.

i am running `bluetoothlegatt` sample from android only.

Comment: can you post the link of app or project

Comment: i dont have the direct link as i have imported from studio itself but here is the guild `http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/bluetooth-le.html`

Comment: then paste the code if it is only only 2 or 3 clases

Comment: I have worked on ble I might help u

Comment: @ShakeebAyaz here is the link `https://github.com/googlesamples/android-BluetoothLeGatt`

Comment: This project is working for me..what is your minsdk and targeted sdk

Comment: mininum  19 and targeted 21 , are you able to see other android device too after scanning

Comment: This project will only scan BLE or iBeacon not other bluetooth devices